# Cant add space between cols, without row change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to add a space between my col's but still have the 3 boxes at 1 row at size 4. I've tried adding margin to`.col-style-3` witch ofcause did not work, but push them off position. Also i've tried to add padding, but since i'm using a border, the padding will just push away my border. I've also tried to add `col-sm-12` inside my `col-sm-4` witch can work, but the transaction works wired then, and i know it's not the right way to do it. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue, i'm not looking for more than 10-15px space between my boxes.

Image of how it does look now: [image]

This is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var Site in Model)
    {
        <a target="_blank" href="@Site.Url">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-style-3">
                <img class="CasinoImage" src="~/Content/Img/@Site.ImageName" />
                <h2>@Site.Name</h2>
                <hr />
                <h3>Denne side tilbyder:</h3>
                <span class="OfferStyle">
                    @Site.Bonuses
                </span>
                <hr />
                <div class="ClickMeBox">Hent din bonus nu</div>
                @if (@Site.DepositRequired == true)
                {
                    <span class="DepositStyle">INDBETALING ER NØDVENDIGT</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span class="DepositStyle">INGEN INDBETALING NØDVENDIGT!</span>
                }
            </div>
        </a>
    }
</div>
```

This is my styling:

```
    .col-style-3 {
    padding: 0px !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
    .col-style-3 > a  {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .col-style-3:hover {
        border: solid 1px #bebebe;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #adadad;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

Comment: whats the css for the `.row` and `.col-sm-4`

Comment: @OnlineUser02094 Normal bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make the width 1/3 of the size MINUS padding and spacing.

In the example below, I had a `0.5rem` margin around each div. If each div is 33.3%, then they will push out of the 100% container because the margin space still takes up space. So, I did `width: calc((33.3%) - 1rem` and it. I added an extra 2px for the border.

Check out my[CodePen](https://codepen.io/emily28144/pen/abbodeQ)

Comment: Thanks for the answere. Doing that, they still push the 3rd down. Remember i'm using col-sm-4 and not col-sm-3 :)

Comment: ok well try 25% width then. And also adjust the amount of margin you have

Comment: I fixed it by going into bootstrap and change col-sm-4 from 33,333xxx to 32, and then going give my col-style-3 margin 0.6677%.Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Note : please use bootstrap css for this

```css
.col-xs-4{padding: 0 15px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, i got fixed it by chaning the col-sm-4 % in bootstrap.min.css, i had tried adding a padding, but the problem would be that it would push away the border i had. Thanks again

Comment: welcome.!! but JFI can you please put border on img tag not on col-xs-4. that's the reason to border push away for padding.    EX: <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000" style="border:1px solid #000;">

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making your `div.col-sm-4` containers direct children of the `div.row` with a class of `border-0` (removes the border from outer container) and then your div within the anchor tag would look something like `<div class="col-style-3 border">`. Demo: https://codepen.io/chasewoodford/pen/VwwZaQe

Comment: And actually you can omit the `.border` and `.border-0` classes from my example since you're handling borders in your custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 30px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }        
        .col-style-3 {
            padding: 0px !important;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        .col-style-3 > a  {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .col-style-3:hover {
            border: solid 1px #bebebe;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #adadad;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        .CasinoImage {
            background-color: #024c32;
            width: 100%;
            height: 244px;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none !important;
            outline: none !important;
            border: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }
        .center {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .Denneside {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .Denneside h3 {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        }
        .Denneside span {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .ClickMeBox {
            background-color: #ff6a00;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        }
        .Box {
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 border-0">
                <a target="_blank" href="@Site.Url">
                    <div class="col-style-3 border">
                        <img class="CasinoImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain" />
                        <h2 class="center">Danske Spil</h2>
                        <div class="Denneside">
                            <h3>Denne side tilbyder:</h3>
                            <span class="OfferStyle">100% Indbetaling + 50 FreeSpins</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ClickMeBox">HENT DIN BOUNUS NU</div>
                        <div class="Box">INDBETALING ER NODVENDIGT</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 border-0">
                <a target="_blank" href="@Site.Url">
                    <div class="col-style-3 border">
                        <img class="CasinoImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain" />
                        <h2 class="center">Danske Spil</h2>
                        <div class="Denneside">
                            <h3>Denne side tilbyder:</h3>
                            <span class="OfferStyle">100% Indbetaling + 50 FreeSpins</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ClickMeBox">HENT DIN BOUNUS NU</div>
                        <div class="Box">INDBETALING ER NODVENDIGT</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 border-0">
                <a target="_blank" href="@Site.Url">
                    <div class="col-style-3 border">
                        <img class="CasinoImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain" />
                        <h2 class="center">Danske Spil</h2>
                        <div class="Denneside">
                            <h3>Denne side tilbyder:</h3>
                            <span class="OfferStyle">100% Indbetaling + 50 FreeSpins</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ClickMeBox">HENT DIN BOUNUS NU</div>
                        <div class="Box">INDBETALING ER NODVENDIGT</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```